# Why do I get a magic value error when loading a class file created with ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode

I wrote a `byte` array created with ASM to a file using the following code:

```
try(FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(classname + ".class")) {
        stream.write(res);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file is loaded using the following code:

```
@Override
public Class<?> findClass(String name) {
    for(URL url : getURLs()) {
        File file = new File(url.getPath().substring(1) + name + ".class");
        if(file.exists()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("found class");
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader(file));
                return super.defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);             
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The class is found by my `ClassLoader`, but I get a ClassFormatError the magic value is 4022320623.

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Your `res` data is probably not a properly-formatted `.class` file.  How did you determine `res`?  What does "created with ASM" mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=4022320623

Comment: ASM is a framework to create java byte code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the way the file is read (using Apache's Commons IO library). Using the following to read the file works just fine:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Comment: The problem is not the `toByteArray` of the Apache library, but the fact that you are passing a `FileReader` to it, which is designed for text reading, rather than the appropriate `FileInputStream`. You can say that the existence of a method accepting a `Reader` is misleading, but that might be one of the reasons why the method [has been deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.Reader)). Of course, if you are using Java 7 or newer, you can just use `Files.readAllBytes` without any 3rd party library.

Comment: If you are at it, you may also use [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) for storing the byte array.